# comparing two partial correlation coefficients (spearman)

Tags: bootstrap, spearman-rho, partial-correlation

I have carried out the following two spearman partial correlations using the "ppcor" package in R:

-- Coefficient 1 = Correlation of A1 with B controlling for C;

-- Coefficient 2 = Correlation of A2 with B controlling for C.

I have a set 234 words. For each word I have different measures (A1 and A2 are two versions of the same measure, and B and C are in common as you can see. I would like to compare the two Spearman partial Rhos but I am not sure how to proceed.

My idea would be to use bootstrapping to generate a distribution of absolute difference between the two partial correlation coefficients, to then extract the 95% confidence interval and see if it includes 0.

Do you have any suggestions?

here is the distribution of B outcome:

[image]

here is the scatterplot of the relationship between A1/A2 and B:

[image]

And here is the scatterplot of the relationship between A1/A2 and B with A1/A2 transformed for graphical purposes (Note, this transformation does not affect Spearman or Kendall tests as they are based on ranks):

[image]

Comment: Perhaps regression and compare betas, this will allow you to examine the magnitude of the association and control for C.

Comment: thanks coconn41. After taking the log10 of the A1/A2 (for graphical purposes), the relationship between A1/A2 and B seems something like y=1/x. More importantly, the error around this potential model is much larger for smaller values of A1/A2. Also, there are outliers in the data which it does not make sense to exclude for now. Do you think regression can still be applied? I used Spearman (and Kendall gives same results) because it makes no assumptions about the distribution of the data.

Comment: Can you post a graph / histogram of the distribution of your dependent variable? And also a scatter plot of your A1 against B and A2 against B?

Comment: Or if you know how they are distributed you can just state it.

Comment: Sure thanks, I have edited my original question adding the plots you asked.

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood. In addition to the comparative scatterplots, I am also looking for a histogram of only your outcome (in your case B), to note its distribution. This will help determine if regression is appropriate. Also, a more detailed explanation of your goals and what each variable represents would be helpful.

Comment: sorry, I just updated the first plot above (it is the same but it was shown twice before which was confusing). It is now the distribution of the outcome B (using a density plot instead of histogram because the variable is continuous).
B is the average stage of acquisition of a word, the predictor is the number of different character sequences (which include the target word) that an algorithm produces.
A1 and A2 are two different computational models.

Comment: Hmmm. So you are attempting to see which algorithm is a better predictor of average stage of acquisition of a word? If that's the case I'm not quite sure if either correlation or regression is the best method for this. But it's possible that regression could help. You could try transforming your outcome variable to make it a normally distributed and then use linear regression while controlling for C. I would get a second opinion though.

Comment: Thanks coconn41 for your time and opinion on this